# Android reading text file with signal, putting it into ArrayList and ploting

Tags: android, arraylist, plot, signals

I'm trying to analyse ECG signal. I have to get numbers from .txt
Numbers are separated by space. I want to store them in ArrayList. There will be about 500 000 numbers in one ArrayList. Is ArrayList a good choice? Or maybe should I think about SQLite?

```
-0.165 -0.365 -0.435 -0.425 -0.370 -0.330 -0.325
```

What should I use to read these numbers separately?

Right now I've sth like this:

```
public static String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
    InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

    String line;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
```

I have to change it. I need to read numbers separately and put them to ArrayList. Not StringBuilder. What should i do?

Comment: See basically ArrayList is used to store data index wise. So as per your scenario ArrayList is not good option. SQLite is better way to fetch data instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`There will be about 500 000 numbers in one ArrayList. Is ArrayList a good choice?`

I would use sqlite if you are thinking of doing this operation several times.

You can use Scanner, it goes by space as default delimiter:

```
ArrayList <Integer> array_list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner sc2 = null;
try {
    $file = new File(resId)
    sc2 = new Scanner(new File(file));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {
        Scanner s2 = new Scanner(sc2.nextLine());
    while (s2.hasNext()) {
        String s = s2.next();
        //do whatever you need: ej.System.out.println(s);
        array_list.add(s);
    }
}
```

Finally I suggest you [AChartEngine](https://github.com/jondwillis/AChartEngine) or [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)